# Payload.getIssuee() is deprecated

Tags: java, android, google-api, authorization, deprecated

I have the below piece of code that checks the token and authorises the Google user login

```
GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience))
    mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getIssuee()))
    mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
```

The `getIssuee()` method is deprecated. Does anyone know what to use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Use `getAuthorizedParty()` instead. Refer to [this link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/auth/openidconnect/IdToken.Payload#getAuthorizedParty())